# How convert utf8 string to utf16 string in python3

Tags: python, sqlite, utf-8, octave, utf-16

I have whole source code in utf8 (using "# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-" on second line)

In code I select from sqlite database string-value using sqlalchemy

```
sel = u'SELECT name FROM station WHERE id == ...'
value = getattr(engine.execute(sel).fetchone(), u'name')
```

in database is column `name` created this way

```
Column(u'name', String(length=32, convert_unicode=True)
```

After `select` I need convert `value` to utf16 (due to sending to Octave by SciPy)

How I can do this?

I try

```
value = value.encode(u'utf-8').decode(u'utf-16')
```

but Octave still not accept some special characters (for expamle ě,š,č,ř,...)

PS.: I do this in function. I add `value` to dictionary

```
updated_dict[u'name'] = value
```

then return `updated_dict` to caller function and export to .mat file

```
scipy.io.savemat(filename,{u'save_struct':updated_dict})
```

Comment: Why do you think you need to set `convert_unicode`?

Comment: I try it without this argument too (before I meet this problem). So I try something for repair it and now I leave it in code. It seem it is not needed in my case...

Answer (score 0):

`value` should be a Unicode object already. Ignoring the fact the you're totally bypassing the power of Sqlalchemy to run a SQL manually for a simple query, you ought to be able to do:

```
utf16_value = value.encode('utf-16')
```

I would also question why Octave needs utf-16 data.